# stray '@' in program

Tags: macos, cocoa, qt

I want to use `NSRunningApplication` in my Qt application on Mac OS X.
I tried to include these header files in `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include Cocoa/Cocoa.h
#include Foundation/Foundation.h
#include AppKit/NSRunningApplication.h
#include AppKit/NSWorkspace.h
#include ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h
#include "CGWindow.h".
```

Also included following in `.pro` file

```
INCLUDEPATH     += /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers
```

But this gives error: `stray '@' in program`

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:6:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:6,
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:8 : error: stray '@' in program.
```

My question is:
How to use `NSRunningApplication` in my application? 
Which file(s) to include and where/how to remove these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an objc file instead. Change the extension to .mm and use objc directive to import framework:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil for showing us the right direction... but can you please tell us a bit more like - should we use the main.mm file instead of main.cpp file OR something else. Please elaborate and include some more code if possible and/or applicable.

Comment: No, only files where you're using obj-c should be mm files